# PHPicker - All selected UIImages returning nil

Tags: swift, uiimage, photo, phpickerviewcontroller

Good day.

I'm using `PHPicker` in order to implement the use of selecting multiple photos and I've encountered an issue when trying to handle the deselecting action.

When I deselect one of the pre-selected photos from the photo library after opening it up for the second time, all of the images suddenly become `nil` and I get a `Could not coerce an item to class UIImage` error in `canLoadObject(_:)` and `loadObject(_:)`. Because of this, it never enters my if loop and the deselection action can never be done.

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    let identifiers = results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
    self.parent.imageIdentifierArray = identifiers
        
    // unpack the selected items
    for image in results {
        if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] newImage, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Can't load image \(error.localizedDescription)") // GETTING THIS ERROR WHEN I OPEN THE PHOTO LIBRARY FOR THE SECOND TIME AND DESELECT A PHOTO
                } else if let image = newImage as? UIImage {
                    // Add new image and pass it back to the main view
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let index = self!.parent.selectedPhotos.firstIndex(where: { $0.pngData() == image.pngData() }) {
                            self!.parent.selectedPhotos.remove(at: index)
                        } else {
                            self!.parent.selectedPhotos.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error loading asset")
        }
    }
    // close the modal view
    parent.isPresented = false
}
```

Comment: no :( i ended up using an external library called YPImagePicker

Answer (score 0):

```
for result in results {
        result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] object,
            error in
            if let image = object as? UIImage {
                let fileName = result.assetIdentifier
                self?.imageArray.append(ImageData.init(image: image, fileName: fileName ?? "Empty Name"))
            } else {
                let fileName = result.assetIdentifier
                //  let identifiers = results.ompactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
                let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [fileName ?? ""], options: nil)
                
                if let image = fetchResult.firstObject?.image {
                    self?.imageArray.append(ImageData.init(image: image, fileName: fileName ?? "Empty Name"))
                }
            }
            if results.count == self?.imageArray.count {
                print("Images: \(self?.imageArray)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

extension PHAsset {

var image : UIImage {
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

// if you want original image use PHImageManagerMaximumSize as targetSize
    imageManager.requestImage(for: self, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: { image, _ in
        thumbnail = image!
    })
    return thumbnail
}
```

}

there is a workaround, you can get image using PHAsset using asset identifier